# PHP warning about POSIX collating element

Tags: php, regex, apache, preg-replace

I've got a PHP warning message below

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed:
>   POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset 71 in
>   ****/bbcode.php on line 244

here is in line 244 of bbcode.php

```
$config['text'] = preg_replace('#(^|[ \t\r\n"“\'])(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))#ui', '$1[url]$2[/url]', $config['text']);
```

Any suggestion to avoid this warning ?
(without editing anything in server config)

I use 
PHP Version 5.2.17 and Apache 2.0

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation failed: POSIX collating elements are not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173787/compilation-failed-posix-collating-elements-are-not-supported)

Comment: Please first make sure you're not reinventing the wheel here: http://php.net/bbcode

Comment: Do you really want to be maintaining this monster regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's assuming you meant this sequence:

```
[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.]
```

...as a collating element ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)) because of the `[.` and `.]`.  Try using `\.` to escape the dots instead of `[.]`.