# Regex to match all lines not starting with ==

Tags: regex, perl

This should be simple, but I've been having trouble with it. I want to write a regex in perl to match all lines that do not begin with an "==". I created this expression:

^[^\=\=].*

Which works fine in a regex tester I use, but when I run the perl script I get an error stating:

POSIX syntax [= =] is reserved for future extensions in regex

And the script terminates. I assume I'm using some syntax wrong, but I haven't found anything regarding this. Does anyone have a better way to match these lines?

Comment: check the answer from tchrist from below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173787/compilation-failed-posix-collating-elements-are-not-supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how *character classes* work in regular expressions

A character class is delimited by square brackets `[...]` and generally will match *any one* of the characters that it encloses. So `[abc]` will match `a`, `b`, or `c`, but only the first character of `aa` or `cbc`. You probably know that you can also use *ranges*, such as `[a-c]`

You can also *negate* the class, as you have done, so `[^a]` will match any one character that *isn't* an `a`, such as `z` or `&`, but only the first character of `zz`

Replicating a character in a class will not change what it matches, so `[aardvark]` will match exactly one of `a`, `d`, `k`, `r`, or `v`, and is equivalent to `[adkrv]`

Your regex pattern uses the character class `[^\=\=]`. It's unnecessary to escape an equals sign, and replicating it has no effect, so you have the equivalent of `[^=]`, which will match any single character other than the equals sign `=`

The reason you got that error message is that character classes beginning `[=` and ending `=]` (just `[=]` doesn't count) are reserved for special behaviour yet to be implemented. As above, there would ordinarily be no reason to write a character class with multiple occurrences of the same character, so it's reasonable to disallow such a construction

[`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) has this to say

> **POSIX syntax [= =] is reserved for future extensions in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%s/**
>
> (F) Within regular expression character classes ([]) the syntax beginning with "[=" and ending with "=]" is reserved for future extensions. If you need to represent those character sequences inside a regular expression character class, just quote the square brackets with the backslash: "[=" and "=]". The <-- HERE shows whereabouts in the regular expression the problem was discovered. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

A solution depends on how you want to use the test in your Perl code, but if you need an `if` statement then I would simply invert the test and check that the line *doesn't* start with `==`

```
unless ( /^==/ )
```

or, if you're allergic to Perl's `unless`

```
if ( not /^==/ )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is incorrect, as it fails with `=A` as input, by example.
A way to do it would be with a Perl Compatible Regular Expression(PCRE): `^(?!==)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see why that makes more sense than what I did.